# System.NullReferenceException при взаимодействии с public static List<string>

Tags: c#

Есть список переменных:
`public static List<string> currentpath;` Он объявлен в том же классе, что и основной код.
При попытке доступа в него, допустим с помощью `currentpath.Add("Example");` выдает такую ошибку: 
`System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."`

Помогите разобраться в проблеме.

---

P.S. Я знаю, что такое `System.NullReferenceException`, однако я не могу понять, почему вылетает подобная ошибка, ведь переменная публична и статична, и такой ошибки быть не должно.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` никак не связано с публичностью и статичностью. Исключение возникает при попытке вызова метода через ссылку, которая указывает на `null`. Если Вы это понимаете то задайте вопрос вида: «почему `currentPath` равен `null`» и распишите где и как инициализируется `currentPath`.

Comment: "ведь переменная публична и статична, и такой ошибки быть не должно." - а Вы ей хоть что-то где-то присвоили, перед тем как делать Add? default для экземпляров класса null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static List<string> currentpath = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Списки являются объектами, поэтому ДО обращения к ним их следует создавать, вызывать их конструктор